# Add padding to sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress, padding, sidebar

I've tried many ways to add padding to my sidebar widgets without success when I make the changes via Developer Tools it works, but I get stuck when I try to find the right tag to call, since I'm using a theme that might have different tag names¿? (I'm sorry if this sounds dumb but I'm kinda new to this, my site is http://thenoirportrait.com, as you can see for example the Social Media blocks are stick to the sidebar divider. These are two of the many codes I've tried to use in my child theme:

```
.sidebar.widget-area.position-right {
    padding-left: 40px!important;
    padding-right: 40px!important;
}


.xt-widget-content {
    padding-left: 40px!important;
    padding-right: 40px!important;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: You sure the site is loading the child style sheet after the parent theme styles? In developer tools click on network and reload the page and make sure.

Comment: Yes, all the other codes I have in my child theme are working just fine, I think the thing is to find the tag for the widgets, cause I think there is an specific one with this "xt" like other tags I'm also using :/

Now I think it would be better to just add padding to the Social Media blocks but even finding a tag that works for that is being a headache for me

Comment: seems like ou could make adjustments in this file:  http://thenoirportrait.com/wp-content/themes/goodnews/lib/widgets/assets/common/css/styles.css?ver=4.4.7

Comment: I just made the changes but nothing happens, I don't understand why this is being so hard :(

Answer (score 0):

Leave a space between the "px" and "!important":

```
.sidebar.widget-area.position-right {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
    padding-right: 40px !important;
}
```

Apart from that, this selector should work

Comment: Thank but nope, it doesn't work. It's still stick to the divider :(